# How to deploy ssrs report on production server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportserver

I had created few SSRS reports on the development environment. Now I need to deploy those reports to the production environment. The production environment server name & database names are different from development environment.

Kindly let me know the proper procedure for deployment.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create two different ptoject configurations in the configuration manager - name them f.e. "Development" and "Production". Then, in the project properties, set up the server names and report folders for both prod and dev configurations as necessary. By doing this you will be able to choose a right configuration when deploying and your reports will be deployed to a correct server.
2. It is not that straight forward for different databases though. What I would suggest here is to create a shared datasources in both development and production environments with the same name, configure the connecction strings properly and use the shared datasource in your reports. You will need to create the datasources only once, and all the consiquent deployments will still refer to those datasources.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To deploy the report go to Project > Project properties and the following window shall open up [image]

Fill the server name in TargetServerURL (marked 1 in red). Your server name should be http://{servername}/RerportServer. 
After this you can use a custom folder where you want to deploy the reports (this is marked as 2). Keep the rest as same.

Since you have different DB names as well you can do a number of things to address this issue.

1. You can create a shared Data Source like @Alexey pointed out.
2. Press CTRL+Alt+D to open up Report Data menu and create a new Data Source, copy your query there and redesign.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am getting `The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.` error

Comment: Open your application as an administrator. If that doesn't help then look in to the security settings of Report Server and see if you have access to it.

Comment: I have all the permissions and I want to use production server

Comment: Twix please give little more detail than that. When do yo get the error? When deploying or accessing it? Have you tried accessing the report server itself? Can you access the report server on your production environment  by going to http://{servername}/RerportServer?

Comment: I can access the report on the report server on my development machine but when I try to access the same report within my application is is throwing the above error